# PHP error logging. How to prevent?

Tags: php, error-handling, php-ini

How can I prevent php error logging in php? I can print errors, but I can't disable error logging(all php errors are appended to `error_log` in my host). I have tried to search the net, but I haven't find anything(exept solutions which are not working for me). 
My function that shows errors:

```
function show_errors($log = false) {

    if ($log) {
      // so what here?
    }

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

}
```

But remember. I can't use `php_flag`s or `php_value`s in my .htaccess file because my web server has blocked them.

Comment: Why would you want to hide errors? They're there for a reason - so you can see what's not working and fix it.

Comment: My function prints errors in the page, so i don't need error logging then, @andrewsi.

Comment: Consider it a belts-and-braces approach, in that case :)

Comment: Yea but I would use this functionality when i debug my just-coded phps.

Comment: Ask web host support to disable it manually for your domain, Since they can modify apache config

Comment: @revo. I want to disable them temporarily like function, not permanently.

Comment: I guess you already tried `error_reporting` http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your php.ini does not have `safe_mode` or `open_basedir` in effect, you can do this

```
ini_set('error_log', '/dev/null');
```

You can also use .htaccess at your docroot and add

```
php_value error_log /dev/null
```